Disabling ALL animations on MATE 22.04
I've tried various gsetting values under gnome, mate, marco, gtk using dconf editor or the gsettings command directly, and none disable them even temporarily, let alone permanently!!!
The first thing I tried was MATE Tweak, and that had no effect!
I did not see any guidance on the MATE site that dealt with a "stubborn" computer scenario.
Places where I looked for guidance (among others) were:

disable-all-mate-animations-in-ubuntu-mate-20-04
how-do-i-turn-off-gnome-shell-activities-animations

The other references all seemed to duplicate the above.
So ... I went looking using dconf-editor, under org for each of

ArcticaProject
gnome
gtk
mate
onboard

and toggled ALL animation properties anywhere to ON, then OFF, to ensure I told the system what I wanted, and that it would register somewhere. Unfortunately, none of that gave the desired result!
Please HELP!
Window Manager: Marco (picom: GLX)

Linux hostname 5.15.0-116-generic #126-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 1 10:14:24 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Release 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.15.0-116-generic x86_64
MATE 1.26.0
Memory: 3.6 GiB
Processor: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 810 Processor × 4
Graphics: AMD RS780 (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.15.0-116-generic, LLVM 15.0.7)

